# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline: docker not found during docker build

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
pipeline {

    agent any
    environment {
        registry = "abcd"
        registryCredential = 'docker_artifactory'
        IMAGE_REPO_NAME = 'abcd/text-train'
        IMAGE_TAG = '0.0.1'
    }      
    stages {      
        stage("Clone repo") {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Build training image'){
            steps{
                   script{ 
                        dockerImage = docker.build "${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
                      }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Jenkins pipeline fails with an error

> script.sh: line 1: docker: not found

Comment: Check if docker is installed on the environment running the pipeline and if the user has permission to run docker.

Comment: how do I check if docker is installed on the environment or not? currently I have given a private repository name where I want to push the docker image , in the environment section

Comment: try to access the terminal of the machine expected to execute the pipeline scripts and run docker commands. Assuming the user `jenkins` is running the pipeline scripts, it needs to have permission to use the docker command.